# Unity 5 Object translation and rotation

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, rotation, translate

I am having an issue in unity where my object will do a translation and then nothing else, I want a sequence of translations and rotations to occur but it only does the first translation in the code and wont stop, I tried using a separate function to execute the translation instead of the Update function but this didn't work either, please help.

```
void Update () 
{
    if (enemyHit == false)
    {
        //enemy moving
        transform.LookAt(TTarget);


    }
    else if (enemyHit == true)
    {
        Debug.Log (enemyHit);

        Evade();
    }
}

IEnumerator Wait(float duration)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
}

void Evade()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
    Wait(2);
    transform.Rotate(0,90,0);



}
```

Comment: Depending on the value of `enemyHit`, you may be calling `transform.LookAt` once per frame, which would tend to overwrite any other rotations that you're trying to do.

Comment: Looking at your new question, it looks like my answer solved your problem. You can go ahead and accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A coroutine function should not be called directly like a normal function. You must use `StartCoroutine` to call it.

```
void Evade()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
    StartCoroutine(Wait(2););
    transform.Rotate(0,90,0);
}
```

Even when you fix that, the rotae function will now be called but there will be no waiting for 2 seconds. That's because a normal function does not and will not wait for coroutine function to return if the coroutine function has `yield return null` or `yield return new WaitForSomething`.....

This is what you should do:

You call a coroutine function when `enemyHit` is `true`. Inside the coroutine function, you *translate*, *wait* then *rotate*. I suggest you [learn](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines) about coroutine and understand how it works before using it.

```
void Update()
{
    if (enemyHit == false)
    {
        //enemy moving
        transform.LookAt(TTarget);


    }
    else if (enemyHit == true)
    {
        Debug.Log(enemyHit);
        StartCoroutine(Evade(2));
    }
}

IEnumerator Evade(float duration)
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
}
```